# Hashmap clear values

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap

I have this code. When i clear `ArrayList`, values in `HashMap` clear too. How can i save data?

```
public class Stations extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> cities = new HashMap<>();

    ...

    public void parseFrom() {
        cities.clear();
        ArrayList<String> citiesList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(loadJSON());
            JSONArray jArray = jObject.getJSONArray("citiesFrom");
            String countryTitle = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject jsonObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                if ((countryTitle != null) && (!countryTitle.equals(jsonObject.getString("countryTitle")))) {
                    cities.put(countryTitle, citiesList);
                    citiesList.clear();
                }
                countryTitle = jsonObject.getString("countryTitle");
                citiesList.add(jsonObject.getString("cityTitle"));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

When I use `citiesList.clear();`all values are clearing, but keys still "alive".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because they have the same reference in memory.

Try doing this:

```
cities.put(countryTitle, new ArrayList<String>(citiesList));
```

But, if what you really want is to remove it from the hashmap, you'll have to call `cities.remove(countryTitle)` instead of only clearing the array of cities.